# Woocommerce - Change Add To Cart - To View Details

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have managed to change it here http://iheartdecor.co.uk/shop/

But would like to also change it for 'Featured Products' on the home page http://iheartdecor.co.uk/

Not sure how to do this. Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Featured products have an extra meta field `_featured` set to `yes` which defines that the product is featured.

Create a new template for featured product, with the changes that you want from the `conten-product.php`.

in your `content-product.php` template, you can check whether the current product has `_featured` meta and is set to `yes`. If its featured product, load your custom template for featured product or else the default `content-product.php` template.